# My Namespace extension is not listed in the File open dialog

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, windows-shell, shell-extensions

Background:
I have namespace extension implemented to list folder and files from a server(fetched to through a proprietary APIs). It is displayed under "My Computer" and I am able browse the folders, and sub folder.

The problem:
when I open the file dialog from any application, say visual studio, or notepad, etc. My namespace extension node is not listed

Question:
what is to be done to make the namespace extension available in File Dialogs. What are the relevant registry keys, and are there any special interfaces to be implemented?

Thanks,
Madhusudhana

Comment: WTH do you mean with _'namespace extension'_?? Did you rather mean **filename extension**?

Comment: @g-makulik He means a Shell Namespace Extension. That's a thing that exists.

Comment: I assume you have already checked there are no bitness issues? Also, maybe you should check one of these programs with *Dependency Walker*'s profiling mode: If only to check whether the client code actually loads, or tries to load, your DLL.

Answer (score 4):

You have to mark your extension as `SFGAO_FILESYSANCESTOR`. If the shell doesn't believe your folder contains real files/folders then it won't show it to the user in the common file dialogs since the user wouldn't be able to use it as a target for saving/loading documents.

Comment: It depends on which dialog is being used. The older `GetOpenFileName()` dialog can only display items (virtual or otherwise) that are represented as file system paths. The newer `IFileOpenDialog` dialog can display items that are represented by `IShellItem` (which can be used to represent PIDLs).

Comment: I tried set the flag SFGAO_FILESYSANCESTOR while setting registry value ShellFolder\Attributes. Not much luck :(. Do I have specify this flag for any other interface call? Any special interface to implement?

Comment: @MadhusudanNarayan: `IShellFolder::GetAttributesOf()` needs to return it.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: After setting SFGAO_FILESYSANCESTOR flags GetAttributesOf(), I can see the Namespace extension listed in the FileOpenDialog.